# what does "myimage.%2d.png" mean

Tags: modulus, imagesource

cant believe i could not google this--i know this relates to image padding.  Is it

myimage.%2d.png specifies a sequence like  {myimage.01.png, myimage.02.png, myimage.03.png...

and

myimage.%3d.png specifies a sequence like  {myimage.001.png, myimage.002.png, myimage.003.png...

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your'e dealing with printf() style formatting ( and that's what it looks like to me ) you can use "myimage.%02d.png" to pad with zeros like your first sequence and "myimage.%03d.png" in the second sequence.  You should really add some context to your question though...

Comment: Thanks,  I am trying to play image files with the js plug flipbook.js. But the principle is the same for any image sequence.